# Substitution cipher won't decode, code is killed

Tags: c, encryption, substitution, eclipse-che

I have to decrypt a message (just doing single words at the moment) and turn it back into the proper word. I have an encryption key (a string of 26 letters, where the first letter is what A is turned into, the second is what B turns into, etc) which I need to use to get back to the original word. For some reason my code has no errors, but will not decode, and after a while it's just killed by the servers. No idea why it won't execute the decrypting function properly. Can someone see a problem with my code that I can't?

I've tried the code on Eclipse Che and also codeboard (I'm a new uni student, not a pro yet) and it won't work anywhere. I have a working piece of code which encrypts a message in basically the same way, but the decryption code (which is essentially the same thing but backwards) simply won't work.

In my code, the phrase string is the word that should get decrypted, the alphabet is the alphabet (kinda obvious) and the encryptionKey is the string that represents what each letter of the alphabet gets turned into.

```
char subdecrypt(char *phrase, char *encryptionKey);
char alphabetdecrypt(char *phrase, char x, char *encryptionKey);

int main()
{
    char phrase[206]="NCPPQ NQYRBMY"; 
    char alphabet[200]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char encryptionKey[200]="QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKILOP"; 

    printf("The decryption is:\n");
    subdecrypt(phrase, encryptionKey);

    return 0;
}

char subdecrypt(char *phrase, char *encryptionKey)
{
    char i=0, x=0;
    char alphabet[200]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
    while(phrase[i] != 0)
    {
        while(phrase[i] != encryptionKey[x])
        {
            x++;
        }
        alphabetdecrypt(phrase, x, encryptionKey);
        i++;
    }
}

char alphabetdecrypt(char *phrase, char x, char *encryptionKey)
{
    char alphabet[200]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    encryptionKey[x]=alphabet[x];
    printf("%c", alphabet[x]);
}
```

The phrase that's hard coded with this should be decrypted into PIZZA. But the output is currently nothing, and the code is eventually killed.

Comment: Why are you overwriting your encryption key? If you do that, each letter which occurs more than once will not be correctly decrypted

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to do `while(phrase[i] != '\0'` instead of `while(phrase[i] != 0`

Comment: Also why are you overwriting the encryption key `encryptionKey[x]=alphabet[x];`?

Comment: the problem was that i was overwriting the encryption key! thank you, i didnt see that it was doing that. whoops

Comment: @bellaacaitt Please revert your question to its initial form (with code) and accept the answer see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @bellaacaitt because you edited your original question, other users won't see what was actually asked. this is not the point of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Inside the outer `while` loop in `subdecrypt`, you need to reset `x = 0` before you start checking for the phrase character to be in the encryption key.  Without it, you'll quickly access past the end of `alphabet`.

Answer (score 1):

The encrypted string has a `' '` but its not present in the encryption key, hence your code is getting stuck in `while(phrase[i] != encryptionKey[x])` loop looking for corresponding key.

Apart from that there are two more issues. First is condition in the outer while loop `while(phrase[i] != '\0')` and second is reset of `x`.

Corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>


char subdecrypt(char *phrase, char *encryptionKey);
char alphabetdecrypt(char *phrase, char x, char *encryptionKey);

int main()
{
    char phrase[206]="NCPPQ NQYRBMY"; 
    phrase[13] = '\0';
    char encryptionKey[200]="QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKILOP "; 

    printf("The decryption is:\n");
    subdecrypt(phrase, encryptionKey);

    return 0;
}

char subdecrypt(char *phrase, char *encryptionKey)
{
    char i=0, x=0;
    while(phrase[i] != '\0')
    {
        x = 0;
        while(phrase[i] != encryptionKey[x])
        {
            x++;
        }
        alphabetdecrypt(phrase, x, encryptionKey);
        i++;
    }
}

char alphabetdecrypt(char *phrase, char x, char *encryptionKey)
{
    char alphabet[200]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    printf("%c", alphabet[x]);
}
```

Comment: The reset of x was helpful, thank you. The loop itself was fine.